# temporary block IP that will be send a more than 100 mail per day in POSTFIX

Tags: linux, postfix

I have using the POSTFIX mail server for receiving a mail. Now some spammers send a spam mail continuously. I have some idea to block a IP address who send a mail more than 100 per day. is it possible in POSTFIX or shell script. Let me know?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Postfix documentation, what you are looking for is [Postfix SMTP relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html), specifically [smtpd_client_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions)

The Postfix documentation can be a little dense and intimidating to a newcomer.  There are guides available that can help show how to [Blacklist and Whitelist with Postfix](http://www.linuxlasse.net/linux/howtos/Blacklist_and_Whitelist_with_Postfix) (and I've reproduced some of that guide below).

The essential idea is that first, you set up a file of client_checks.  Next, make a hash of that file using postmap; this improves performance.
Third, in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` add a reference the hash.

The file `/etc/postfix/client_checks` would contain something like this:

```
# Restricts which clients this system accepts SMTP connections from.

example.com               REJECT No spammers
.example.com              REJECT No spammers, from your subdomain
123.45.67.89              REJECT Your IP is spammer
123.45.6.0/24             REJECT Your IP range is spammer
32.1.98.76                OK
example1.com              OK
```

Next, you would run `postmap /etc/postfix/client_checks`

Edit your `main.cf` file to add a reference to the client checks:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks
```

Restart postfix and test for correct operation.  You'd want to test from ideally both a whitelisted IP address and a blacklisted IP address.  If it were me, I would temporarily add a known IP address to the client check and confirm mail from that host is rejected, then remove it from `client_checks` once I was confident the check is working.

---